Colima on Mac Intel assign cpu resources to a container
I'm running Colima on Mac Intel. I have allocated 4 CPUs and 4G memory to colima VM. I use the docker run command to start a container and I want to allocate only 1 CPU for the container using option --cpus=1.0 but when I run nproc in the container I see the result is 4. How do I restrict the container resources to 1.
